# Understanding variable assignment in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I have a pretty basic question:

What is this statement actually doing (specifically the `=>$p`)?

```
foreach ($email->parts as $partno=>$p) {
```

I understand the the basics but the `=>$p` is not clear

Comment: `$partno` is the key, `$p` is value

Comment: thanks for your input akashivskyy - totally worthwhile... Glad you stopped by to help out.  I'm sure you knew everything the day you started... There was no learning required - just brilliant from day 1?  Save your derogatory comments and responses for your mum when she asks you to clean your bedroom next!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is covered in the [manual](http://php.net/foreach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `foreach` loop you can ask for both the key and value to be returned

```
$array = array('cat' => 'Tom', 'mouse' => 'Jerry');
foreach($array as $animal => $name) {
    echo $name . ' is a ' . $animal . '<br>';
}
```

So the loop will output

> Tom is a cat
>   Jerry is a mouse

Answer (score 1):

This synthax is to assign the array key name or object property name to the variable `$partno` and it's value to `$p`.

This way you can do for instance `$email->parts[$partno] = $p;`.

It can be particularly useful if you have parallel arrays with different information bound by the key, so you need this information to obtain related data from the other array when iterating one of them.

For instance:

```
$person = array(
    1 => 'Santa Claus',
    2 => 'Homer Simpson',
    3 => 'Papa Smurf'
);

$location = array(
    1 => 'North Pole',
    2 => 'Springfield',
    3 => 'Smurf village'
);

foreach ($person as $id => $name)
    echo "$name live in {$location[$id]}\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

$partno is the key, $p is value
e.g. `$email->parts = array("key" => "value");`

Read this

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php